# BodyParser urlencode in express 4 and encoding windows-1251

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

External service makes a request to my application , and the POST request body encoding winows- 1251 , but as I understand it , body-parser does not work with windows-1251, and i get a error

POST /api/v1/payment/result 415 76.170 ms - 3073

UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset "WINDOWS-1251"

```
at urlencodedParser (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:102:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at jsonParser (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:107:37)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at logger (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at expressInit (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at query (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:49:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/keler/ask-landing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
```

Prompt decision
I bring your own code .

in App

```
var express         = require('express');
var path            = require('path');
var favicon         = require('serve-favicon');
var logger          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var bb              = require('express-busboy');


var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
bb.extend(app);

require("./config/db.js")();

app.use('/', require('./routes'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});


module.exports = app;
```

in Route

```
var payment = {

    result : function(req, res, next) {

        console.log(req.body);
        res.send("ok");
    }
}

module.exports = payment;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Accept-Charset` header to `Windows-1251` on your request? Also [`body-parser` should support `Windows-1251`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#unsupported-charset-bogus) because it uses [`inconv-lite` to do the encoding/decoding](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite#supported-encodings).

Comment: No, request is notification message from payment system, outside my app.
Thanks for help, i try busboy, but i got same erorr.